# VS 2013's Compiler doesn't see FLTK library but VS's IntelliSense does for project Garland's QSlim

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, include, fltk

All is in title:
In VS 2013 I included FLTK library with adding "C:\fltk-1.3.2" in **Include Directories** and "C:\fltk-1.3.2\lib" in **Library Directories** and when I include

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
```

in my code, IntelliSense recognize the FL's files, but VS's Compiler doesn't:
[image]

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you

EDIT:
Here is, fltk-1.3.2 folder:
[image]

EDIT2:
My code is a script of a project included in solution with several projects. 
Here is the project:
http://mgarland.org/dist/qslim-2.1.tar.gz
It's libgfx project in solution (in project's win32 folder) whom has problem with FL.

Comment: But is `C:\fltk-1.3.2` really the include folder? is it more something like `C:\fltk-1.3.2\include`? Where is `Fl.h` located relative to that folder?

Comment: Look my edit. Fl.h is in C:\fltk-1.3.2\FL.

Comment: Does it work if you put an absolute path in, I'm not suggesting this as a fix but does `#include "C:\fltk-1.3.2\FL\Fl.H"`, also can you post the full contents of your project settings for 'Additional Include Directories' under 'Configuration Properties>C/C++>General', have you delimited the folder using a semi-coln `;`?

Comment: Yes I've delimited the folder using a ";".

Comment: What happens when you switch on C++/Advanced/Show includes?  Just try building one file.  Where is it looking for the includes?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Configuration Properties for your solution does the C/C++ > Command Line tab show `/I "C:\fltk-1.3.2"` ?

Perhaps try changing to:

```
#include <FL\FL.h>
```

Does seem odd that Intellisense is picking it up.

Have a look at some of the additional causes of the [C1083 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34.aspx).

Comment: I added /I "C:\fltk-1.3.2" and test changing #include <FL\FL.h> but there is the same problem. Look my Question's Edit2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Actually, as there are several projects in my program' solution, it was another project (the project **QVis**) which called the file (gui.h in the project **libgfx**) containing the code:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H> ...
```

with external dependencies.

So I had to include the library for this another project too.